# How to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} (2n - \sqrt[3]{8n^3 - 2n^2})$

Tags: limits

How do you calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} (2n - \sqrt[3]{8n^3 - 2n^2})$?

John

Comment: I would ask accurate to hold a

Comment: What are some tools for finding limits that you know about/are willing to use in this Question?  Where did the problem arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[2n-\sqrt[3]{8n^3-2n^2}\right] =  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[2n-2n\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{4n}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]$

Now Using $\displaystyle \bullet\; (1+x)^n = 1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2}+...........\infty $

So Limit $\displaystyle  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2n\cdot \left[1-\left(1-\frac{1}{3\cdot 4n}-\frac{2}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{32n^2}-......\infty\right)\right] = \frac{1}{6}$

Now above we left Higher power of $n$ in Denominator because $\displaystyle  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^{k}}\rightarrow 0\;,$ for $k\geq 1$

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Taylor's formula* at order $1$:
\begin{align*}2n - \sqrt[3]{8n^3 - 2n^2}&=2n\biggl(1-\sqrt[3]{1 -\frac1{4n}}\biggr)=2n\biggl(1-\biggl(1-\frac1{12n}+o\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)\biggr)\biggr)\\&=\frac1{6n}+o(1)\to\frac16.\end{align*}$$